# Cannot Navigate Hyperlink to outside of website

Tags: c#, asp.net, hyperlink

I have two simple aspx pages

```
Viewpage.aspx

<asp:HyperLink ID="lbllink" runat="server" Target="_Blank"></asp:HyperLink>

Editpage.aspx

<asp:TextBox ID="txtlink" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>// client input the link : faceboook.com
```

and in code behind:

```
lbllink.Text= txtlink.Text;// txtlink.Text = facebook.com
lbllink.NavigateUrl = txtlink.Text;
```

When I built, an error occur: `The resource cannot be found.` because `facebook.com` is not a page in my webstie folder.

I cannot use `<a href= >` because it doesnt have `ID` tag.

help, is there any better way for my problem???

Comment: `http://facebook.com` ???

Comment: yes, I want link to http://facebook.com

Comment: you need to http:// part - sorry I did not communicate that well did I

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot guess if its a `relative` or `absolute` url.

If you know it will always be an external url then you need to ensure the entered url has the `http://` prepended else your server will assume its relative to the page it was clicked from.

[The Uri Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.aspx) has some pretty useful `stuff`.

You might find this method useful

```
public static string ToAbsoluteUrl(string relativeUrl) {
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(relativeUrl)) return relativeUrl;
    if(relativeUrl.ToLower().StartsWith("http")) return relativeUrl;

    return String.Format("http://{0}", relativeUrl);
}
```

Comment: oh thank you, cannot believe that I dont know this thing, poor me, I've learned a new thing